# How to obtain TFS build feedback in Visual Studio

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

I'm starting out with continous integration with TFS 2013. I've added a CI build definition, and on each check-in of the code a build is executed. So far, so good. Next I'd like to get some kind of feedback; I can check in a test which fails, for example, and the build-server will fail it but there's not notification in my Visual Studio. How can I get a notification from the build server, straight to the developer who initiates the CI build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a build alert up in the portal to alert the user that their build's not succeeded (i.e. failed or partially succeeded)

```
http://yourTfs:8080/tfs/yourCollection/yourProject/_admin/_alerts#
```